# Spring Social Linkedin - SignIn

Tags: spring-social-linkedin

I am new to Spring social and trying to config spring social signin for linkedin.

My spring config file below,

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tc.web">
<context:include-filter type="regex"
expression="(service|controller|component)\..*" />
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator"
class="org.springframework.social.connect.support. ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
<property name="connectionFactories">
<list>
<bean
class="org.springframework.social.linkedin.connect .LinkedInConnectionFactory">
<constructor-arg value="key........" />
<constructor-arg value="secret .........." />
</bean>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt .Encryptors"
factory-method="noOpText" />

<bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.Jdb cUsersConnectionRepository">
<constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
<constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
<constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository"
factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
<constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
<aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>


<bean id="signInAdapter" class="com.tc.web.social.signin.SocialSignInAdapte r" />

<bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.Prov iderSignInController">
<!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
<constructor-arg ref="signInAdapter" />
<property name="applicationUrl" value="link" />
<property name="signUpUrl" value="link" />
<property name="signInUrl" value="link" />
</bean>
```

My SocialSignInAdapter.java is,

public class SocialSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter{

```
@Override
public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
System.out.println("User Id is ===>>> "+userId);
System.out.println("Connection is ====>>> "+connection);
return null;
}

}
```

In Login.jsp,

```
<li class="linkedin"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/signin/linkedin" title="LinkedIn">&nbsp;</a></li>
```

When I click the above linkedin link, i get 404 error.

I guess my app is unable to find the ProviderSignInController for the request, ://dom:8080/myApp/signin/linkedin.

I suspect the below config in spring xml.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tc.web">
<context:include-filter type="regex"
expression="(service|controller|component)\..*" />
</context:component-scan>
```

I have all my controller inside the package com.tc.web. But the ProviderSignInController is in Spring package and my app is unable to find it.

I tried the below as well.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tc.web,org.springframework.social.con nect.web">
<context:include-filter type="regex"
expression="(service|controller|component)\..*" />
</context:component-scan>
```

I got ambigous mapping error for ProviderSignInController with the above config.
So, I removed the

```
<bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.Prov iderSignInController">
<!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
<constructor-arg ref="signInAdapter" />
<property name="applicationUrl" value="link" />
<property name="signUpUrl" value="link" />
<property name="signInUrl" value="link" />
</bean>
```

from my spring xml. But still I am getting the 404 error.

Could anyone help me on this please ..........

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 1):

The Controller that handles signin requests is org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController (present in spring-social-web-x.x.x.jar)
The Controller method is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{providerId}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView signIn(@PathVariable String providerId, NativeWebRequest request)
```

So, as you can see, it only accepts POST requests. You will have to change the anchor link tag to a button that triggers a form submit.
e.g.

```
<form action="<c:url value="/signin/linkedin" />" method="POST" id="frmLiConnect"></form>
```

Secondly, in order for the Spring Controller, extend the ProviderSignInController with your own dummy Controller so that the Spring class is accessible.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.SignInAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
@Controller
public class SigninController extends ProviderSignInController {

@Autowired
public SigninController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
        UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository,
        SignInAdapter signInAdapter) {
    super(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, signInAdapter);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

}
```

For more details, you can also refer to the Spring Social Showcase examples at the below link.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/showcase/signin

Hope this helps.